# When saving a pandas dataframe to csv how do I retain the columns.name?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, ipython

### Initial Problem

When I run the following in ipython

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(9*np.random.rand(4,4), decimals=1))
df.index.name = 'x'
df.columns.name = 'y'

df.to_csv('output.csv')

df
```

it outputs the following result:

```
y    0    1    2    3
x                    
0  7.6  7.4  0.3  7.5
1  5.6  0.0  1.5  5.9
2  7.1  2.1  0.0  0.9
3  3.7  6.6  3.3  8.4
```

However when I open `output.csv` the "y" is removed:

```
x   0   1   2   3
0   7.6 7.4 0.3 7.5
1   5.6 0   1.5 5.9
2   7.1 2.1 0   0.9
3   3.7 6.6 3.3 8.4
```

How do I make it so that the `df.columns.name` is retained when I output the dataframe to csv?

### Crude workaround

Current crude work-around is me doing the following:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index_label = 'x|y')
```

Which results in `output.csv` reading:

```
x|y 0   1   2   3
0   7.6 7.4 0.3 7.5
1   5.6 0   1.5 5.9
2   7.1 2.1 0   0.9
3   3.7 6.6 3.3 8.4
```

Something better would be great! Thanks for your help (in advance).

### Context

This is what I am working on: https://github.com/SimonBiggs/Electron-Cutout-Factors

This is an example table: https://github.com/SimonBiggs/Electron-Cutout-Factors/blob/master/output/20140807_173714/06app06eng/interpolation-table.csv

Comment: I think part of the reason there's no option for this (AFAIK) is that it's hard to know where the column index name would go- which cell do you think it belongs in, exactly?

Comment: It would be the same display set up that is used as ipython output. "y" would go in cell (1,1), "x" would go in cell (2,1), the top left hand data value would start in cell (3,2).

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a list to name the columns, then you can specify the index name when you are writing to csv:

```
df.columns = ['column_name1', 'column_name2', 'column_name3']
df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', index_label='Index_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  It's slightly different but hopefully usable, since it fits the CSV paradigm:

```
>>> df.columns = ['y{}'.format(name) for name in df.columns]
>>> df.to_csv('output.csv')
>>> print open('output.csv').read()
x,y0,y1,y2,y3
0,3.5,1.5,1.6,0.3
1,7.0,4.7,6.5,5.2
2,6.6,7.6,3.2,5.5
3,4.0,2.8,7.1,7.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, unfortunately that doesn't meet my needs. I care about the numbers that are written in the columns and index.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem my solution causes you?  It seems like what you're asking for will otherwise require you to write your own header rows before asking Pandas to write the body of the CSV.  You can do that if you really need to.

Comment: **First:** I want the code to be as readable and transparent as possible. So minimal complication is important.
**Second:** I am creating a look-up table to be used for interpolation. The axes represent "width" and "aspect ratio", hence the headings.
The full code can be seen at my gihtub [here](https://github.com/SimonBiggs/Electron-Cutout-Factors). An example of one of these interpolation tables can be seen [here](https://github.com/SimonBiggs/Electron-Cutout-Factors/blob/master/output/20140806_150610/06app06eng/interpolation-table.csv).

Comment: I think your "crude workaround" is as good as you're likely to get.

Comment: Okay, thanks John. Also, for future readers, the table link has changed. An example table should now be able to be found [here](https://github.com/SimonBiggs/Electron-Cutout-Factors/blob/master/output/20140807_173714/06app06eng/interpolation-table.csv)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it works fine if the column labels are a multiindex. This seems to be a pandas issue. A solution that works and isn't too ugly would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(9*np.random.rand(4,4), decimals=1))
df.index.name = 'x'
df.columns.name = 'y'
##### Add this line to create another column index level
df.columns = [df.columns, df.columns]

df.to_csv('output.csv')

##### When you read it in, specify that the first two lines are both headers
df2 = pd.read_csv('output.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
##### Drop the extra level
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)

df2
```